# PHPUnit: How to include files for testing using wildcards

Tags: php, phpunit

This seems like a really straightforward thing to do - identify the files for testing with phpunit using a wildcard.  For example, here's my test directory:

```
/test/model/v11_CountryTest.php
/test/model/v11_IndustryTest.php
/test/model/v11_UserTest.php
/test/model/v12_OrgTest.php

/test/model/factory/v11_CountryTest.php
/test/model/factory/v12_OrgTest.php
```

As you can see I have a model including some factories.  Some of my model has been updated to Ver 12 (i.e. v12_OrgTest.php).  I would like PHPUnit to run all the v12 tests, but not the v11 ones.  Is there a way to do this?

I have tried simply `phpunit v12*.php` on the command line but that doesn't work.  Also, I tried specifying the wildcard in a `<file>` tag in the phpunit.xml file (under the particular test suite), with no success.

Per the manual, it looks like I can use the `<groups>` tag but it would mean editing each of the test files.  I'll do this if required, but would like to know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it turns out that you can flag entire classes as belonging to a group, with the following code comments:

```
/**
 * @group GroupName
 */
```

Given that it's so easy, there is hardly any need to be able to use wildcards in file selection.  Thanks Sebastian!

Answer (score 0):

[In the documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html) you can find all the command line options. One of the options is "filter", where you can pass an string which PHPUnit will use to filter the tests to execute, choosing only the test cases that match your string. If you've used namespacing with the version "v12", I think you could filter the desired tests, since PHPUnit uses the whole name of the method (with Namespace and class name)